# How to get prior month data from a selected month

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS, how would I return the prior month data of a selected month. 
`month(lis.s_date=month(getdate()) -1` would get me the prior month data of the current month but I want it to be the prior month of any month selected in SSRS. What would I change getdate() to in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent SSRS expression would be:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Now())
```

**Edit after comment:**

You can substitute any date value into the T-SQL expression, e.g a few ways here:

```
create table dates (dateValue date)

insert into dates select '01-jan-2013'
insert into dates select '01-feb-2013'
insert into dates select '15-feb-2013'

select dateValue
  , lastMonthDate = dateadd(mm, -1, dateValue)
  , lastMonthValue = month(dateadd(mm, -1, dateValue))
  , lastMonthName = datename(mm, dateadd(mm, -1, dateValue))
from dates
```

This just uses a table column instead of the `getdate()` function.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/854ff/1).

Comment: What would the tsql equivalent of 'return prior month data of any selected month' be? I'v only found information on doing 'prior month of current month' but none on prior month of any selected month.

Comment: You just need to use a different value than 'getdate()', which always returns the current day; I've shown a few examples above.